# How does one know how many times to downsample in Harmonic Product Spectrum?

Tags: fft, frequency, signal-analysis

I have been working on a Harmonic Product Spectrum Algorithm. Now, all the literature I've read about the subject tells me to downsample an N amount of times. How does one determine what this N value should be? Here is my implementation of Harmonic Product Spectrum so far. Feel free to tell me if I have gone wrong somewhere.

```
private int HarmonicProductSpectrum(Complex[] fftData, int n){
    Complex[][] data = new Complex[n][fftData.length/n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<data[0].length; j++){
            data[i][j] = fftData[j*(i+1)];
        }
    }
    Complex[] result = new Complex[fftData.length/n];//Combines the arrays
    for(int i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
        Complex tmp = new Complex(1,0);
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){//multiplies arrays together
            tmp = tmp.times(data[j][i]);
        }
        result[i] = tmp;
    }
    //Calculates Maximum Magnitude of the array
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
        Complex c = result[i];
        double tmp = c.getMagnitude();
        if(tmp>max){
            max = tmp;;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index*getFFTBinSize(fftData.length);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could point to some paper which describes the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the pitch source spectrum, the lowest pitch possible, and the FFT length.

If N is too small, the algorithm might miss some higher harmonics that contain a significant fraction of a pitch spectrums energy.  So you need to know how many overtones might be important in your particular pitch source.

However, if N is too large, multiple overtones of a single low pitch could end up in the same bin after downsampling the spectrum, confusing the results.

For very low pitches with extremely rich higher harmonics, these 2 constraints may overlap and thus indicate the need for a longer FFT window for HPS, or even the need for a completely different pitch estimation method.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this paper](http://www.hjortgaard.net/projects/4/download) on page 4. It has a great graphical representation of the algorithm. I'll try to write up some pseudocode here that you can adapt to your language (looks like Java to me) as necessary.

```
/* Harmonic Product spectrum PSEUDOCODE
 * @param fftData Discrete Fourier transform of data
 * @param N Number of times we downsample the spectrum to get HPS
 */
int HPS( Complex[] fftData, int N )
{
    // Find magnitude of the FFT
    Real fullSpectrum[] = absOfComplex(fftData);

    // Keep only the positive frequencies (DC to Nyquist)
    Real spectrum[] = discardNegativeFrequencies(fullSpectrum);

    // Make a new array to store HPS
    Real hps[] = copyOf(spectrum);

    // Perfrom HPS:
    // Go through each downsampling factor
    for (int downsamplingFactor = 1; downsamplingFactor <= N; downsamplingFactor++)
    {
        // Go through samples of the downsampled signal and compute HPS at this iteration
        for(int idx = 0; idx < spectrum.length()/downsamplingFactor; idx++)
        {
            hps[idx] *= spectrum[idx * downsamplingFactor];
        }
    }

    return findIndexOfMax(hps);
}
```

This isn't bug-proof but it should get you started.